# How long does it take to restore from an iCloud backup?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, restore

I have 12.8gb worth of photos and videos and I remember shooting videos in particular that was 1 hour long and another 30 minute one.

Last night it didn't take long for the 5,000 photos (inc. short videos) like a few mins at best to come and the 6,000 photos rest is still pending it says "Downloading 6,0000 xxxx originals" in my Photos app. And my video for example that 1 hour one, (i sometimes record videos for YT on my phone) and the other 30 minute one hasn't come through so i wonder if that is what is slowing the restore process.

Googling online it says it can take 1-4 hours per gb to restore from an iCloud backup...

I was thinking maybe it was faster to restore from iTunes...

iCloud backup total: 14.5gb

Photos and videos: 12.8gb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no definitive answer to this as a lot comes down to network speeds, bandwidth, what else you're currently doing with the device, and so on.

That is why you're finding that *"Googling online it says it can take 1-4 hours per gb to restore from an iCloud backup"* - because there's just too many variables involved. In fact, there are places in the world where 1Gb of data would take even longer than 4hrs to download.

As for your thinking that maybe it would be *"faster to restore from iTunes"*, then it certainly would be if you're talking about a local iTunes backup that contains all of the photos and videos in question. Keep in mind though, a full "restore" means you're restoring your entire iPhone with what's in that backup, meaning that your phone ends up losing any data it currently has since that backup was made.

However, if you have all of the photos and videos also stored on your computer (e.g. in the Photos app on a Mac, etc) then you could use iTunes to sync across the photos/videos you want from that source rather than restoring your divide from a backup.

Comment: Hi @Monomeeth! I also did a full backup on iTunes (which includes all the iCloud photos that weren't on there). Since you're a CAE, my question is this: after doing a full restore from iTunes I get the option to sign in to iCloud (i did a test where if i skipped this, all my photos and videos are still there) but when i did sign in to iCloud later in settings (I don't if this automatically triggers a restore from iCloud as I had already restored from tunes) it started *uploading*, presumably photos and vids that weren't synced properly to iCloud that the iTunes backup did.

Comment: (...) There should be no problem with this right? I mean I can't lose photos on my iPhone from my iTunes backup simply by signing/syncing with iCloud?

Comment: TLDR; basically the iPhone iTunes backup contained the photos and vids that i was missing when i had restored with iCloud. my fear is that if i logged in and signed in again to iCloud after the iTunes restore, that these photos/vids would disappear..can this be possible? I mean people always say backup with iTunes and iCloud (which is what i did) it is just restoring from both them and relying on both of them, if either backup is missing something that the other backup has.

Comment: So, you've already done a full restore from iTunes? If so, any data you had previously on your iPhone that wasn't part of the backup (e.g. photos, messages, etc) will now not be on your phone. As for your iCloud data, what you have available to resync down to your phone will depend on your configuration - e.g. what data you had stored on iCloud, whether Photo Stream is enabled, etc. The photos on your phone should remain on your phone, but if you have enabled iCloud Photos on your iPhone, then your iPhone will automatically upload these to iCloud as a way of saving space on your iPhone.

Comment: Yes, don't worry this backup is very recent. I only restored my iPhone because I had a problem with my service that kept saying "Searching" I reset my network settings etc. and even did a software update...didnt work. SO i decided to do a DFU restore and then it worked, I had mobile signal again! The problem was doing a restore from iCloud..I had a few photos/vids missing... and it has been more than 24hrs, I have fast internet (UK) so I decided to reset it again and restore from my iTunes backup and there it was! I just hope my iTunes backup and my icloud back don't conflict with each other.

Comment: Well, if your iPhone was stored from a very recent backup, then you should be fine as far as data loss is concerned. In your first comment above you said "It started *uploading*..." - Can I ask what was happening on the iPhone screen that made you feel this is what was happening?

Comment: So basically, I have this message when I go to the photos app *now*. I have 6,186 photos, 492 videos and it says **uploading 4,37X items**. This is from a 32gb backup on iTunes. When I restored on just iCloud, I only had 5,XXX photos and 345 videos. My total used storage on iCloud was only 14.5 gb from my post (and I have 50gb total available storage on iCloud - .79p per month) and to the best of my knowledge it was only restoring 2,XXX photos/videos. So my guess is iCloud didnt fully backup my photos and videos like it said it did.

Comment: (...) So perhaps this is why I got this message: **uploading 4,37X items** now - it is uploading photos/videos that aren't on my iCloud.Thinking about it, the iCloud did go fairly quick compared to my iTunes backup. Good thing I did both!

Comment: Yes, I was a tad concerned by the *"Last night it didn't take long for the 5,000 photos (inc. short videos) like a few mins at best to come"* in your question. I would wait for everything to finish and then take stock of where things are at when it's over. Then, if you have any concerns, you know what to seek help with. In case you haven't already, I'd take a look at: [Set up and use iCloud Photos](https://support.apple.com/HT204264).